Do we have Sample Diameter Script using JMeter JSR223 Pre Processors for Authentication, Authorization and Accounting
I tried following the steps mentioned in this link for diameter load testing using JMeter

https://dzone.com/articles/diameter-server-load-testing-a-guide

and got stuck in writing my own AAA module using JSR223 Sampler. Can somebody please help me with sample script which I can directly use or try to expand on it as per my requirement.

The original blog post: How to Test RADIUS Server contains some example code:
import org.tinyradius.packet.*
import org.tinyradius.util.*

RadiusClientRClient = newRadiusClient(vars.get("hostip"), vars.get("secretkey"));
AccessRequestReqPacket = newAccessRequest(vars.get("uname"), vars.get("upass"));
ReqPacket.setAuthProtocol(AccessRequest.AUTH_CHAP);
try {
    RadiusPacketRespPacket = RClient.authenticate(ReqPacket);
    if (RespPacket.ACCESS_ACCEPT == 2) vars.put("$auth_result", "accepted"); else {
        if (RespPacket.ACCESS_CHALLENGE == 11) vars.put("$auth_result", "challenged"); else {
            if (RespPacket.ACCESS_REJECT == 3) vars.put("$auth_result", "rejected");
            elsevars.put("$auth_result", "unknown");
        } log.info("Not authenticated");
    }
} catch (Exceptione) {
    System.out.println("The authentication request has been failed!"); vars.put("$auth_result", "failed");
}


Thanks Ivan for the response but I am more interested in diameter as opposed to radius. Do we have any steps to integrate Diameter or JDiameter into JMeter for Load Testing.
